# Azure AD B2C Custom Policy does not yield a valid Apple idp_access_token for the Apple revoke token endpoint

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect, access-token, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, sign-in-with-apple

Apple currently has requirements of being able to delete a user account and revoke token permissions to have an app on their store:

- Endpoint Doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/revoke_tokens
- Additional Info: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/708415

Following the guide here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/idp-pass-through-user-flow?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

the idp_access_token claim yields a string value like "af42702403427436e915f761ddd1e0ed4.0.srrst.aOw1NWI0uV78qwwNrzV7VA" which is not a valid token for apple's auth revoke endpoint's parameters.

Here is a code Snippet of the apple claims provider in the TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml:

```
<ClaimsProvider>
<Domain>apple.com</Domain> <DisplayName>Sign in with Apple</DisplayName> <TechnicalProfiles>
<TechnicalProfile Id="Apple-OIDC">
<DisplayName>Sign in with Apple</DisplayName> 
<Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect"/> 
<Metadata>
<Item Key="ProviderName">apple</Item>
<Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize</Item> 
<Item Key="AccessTokenEndpoint">https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token</Item>
<Item Key="JWKS">https://appleid.apple.com/auth/keys</Item>
<Item Key="issuer">https://appleid.apple.com</Item>
<Item Key="scope">name email openid</Item>
<Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
<Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
<Item Key="external_user_identity_claim_id">sub</Item>
<Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
<Item Key="client_id">xxxxx</Item>
<Item Key="IdTokenAudience">xxxxx</Item>
<Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">0</Item>
<Item Key="ReadBodyClaimsOnIdpRedirect">user.email user.name.firstName user.name.lastName</Item>
</Metadata>
<CryptographicKeys><Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="xxxxx" /> </CryptographicKeys>
<InputClaims />
<OutputClaims>
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="sub" Required = "true"/>
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="user.email" Required = "true"/>
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="user.name.firstName" DefaultValue="" />
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="user.name.lastName" DefaultValue="" />
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="https://appleid.apple.com/" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" /> 
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProviderAccessToken" PartnerClaimType="{oauth2:access_token}" />
</OutputClaims> 
<OutputClaimsTransformations>
<OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" /> 
<OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" /> 
<OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" /> 
<OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId" />
</OutputClaimsTransformations>
<UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />
</TechnicalProfile> 
</TechnicalProfiles> 
</ClaimsProvider>
```

Info on editing Open Id Technical Profiles can be found here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect-technical-profile

Trying to modify the item "MetaData" of the technical profile's MetaData element to include the "v2.0" Open Id Configurations URL as discussed here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/750245/azure-ad-b2c-how-to-get-idp-access-token-for-apple.html results in an "access_denied" error during the b2c authentication with apple.

Not sure how I can get a valid Apple Access token to be passed through. Any thoughts on the matter would be appreciated. If I proceed to delete the user from b2c and am unable to revoke the apple tokens and reset the "sign in with apple" state then the next time a user uses that apple account to create a b2c account then the email and names claims won't be passed through because from apple's perspective they only send that info once and that authorization hasn't been revoked.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue,
the jwt created for the client_secret parameter of the revoke auth apple endpoint was not correctly created from the client secret causing a 400 bad request return..

so the idp_access_token claim yielded from this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/idp-pass-through-user-flow?pivots=b2c-custom-policy
is indeed valid for the apple endpoint specified here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/revoke_tokens

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).